# How to ensure that operation was included in a block with taquito

Tags: javascript, dapps

When I inject an operation using the taquito library, how can I have my program wait for a specific number of blocks after my operation is included in the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taquito return an operation object for each operation you inject using it.

For instance if you do:

```
const op = Tezos.contract.transfer({to: address, amount: 1})

You can wait until the confirmation with 

await op.confirmation();

Or

op.then(() => {
// post operation logic here
})
```